# How python pass by reference?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I tried to implement delete a node in a BST.
And here is my partial code.

```
def delete(node,key):
#Locate that node with value k
    cNode=node
    target=None
    while cNode:
        if cNode.value==key:
            target=cNode
            break
        elif node.value>key:
            cNode=cNode.lChild
        elif node.value<key:
            cNode=cNode.rChild
    target=None
    return node
```

When I tried to use the above method to delete a leaf node. I failed. when the method return, it did nothing to original BST. So what's the problem of this code? I assume it should have something about how python pass arguments by reference? But I am confused now.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no code here that removes anything from your tree. You probably need to sever the link between a parent and a child

Comment: But I set the target node which is the leaf node to None, it should also change the original tree, right?

Comment: Python already passes _values_ by reference; it never silently copies anything. But it doesn't pass _variables_ by reference because that would be meaningless; Python variables aren't memory locations, they're just names in some namespace.

Comment: @lexie, no, target is just a local variable in your `delete` function, you set that to None.

Comment: @nos: I think the OP understands that, or he wouldn't ask the question; he just doesn't understand _why_ it's true, or what he should do instead.

Comment: No, not right. You change the value of the variable `target` to `None` even if before if was a reference to the same object as `cNode`. That does nothing with the referred object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`target = None` only *rebinds* the variable `target` to a new value, `None`. Whatever `target` was bound to before doesn't change.

You'll have to track the *parent node* and set it's `lChild` or `rChild` attribute to `None` instead.

```
def delete(node,key):
    cNode = node
    target = parent = None
    while cNode:
        if cNode.value == key:
            target = cNode
            break
        elif cNode.value > key:
            parent, cNode = cNode, cNode.lChild
        elif cNode.value < key:
            parent, cNode = cNode, cNode.rChild

    if target:
        if parent:
            if parent.lChild is target:
                parent.lChild = None
            else:
                parent.rChild = None
        else:
            # target is top-level node; perhaps return None in that case?
    return node
```

Comment: Thanks Martjin, I see my problem.

Comment: Yep, I will and it seems I can only do that in 2 mins